# Java loop on multiple HTML table rows

Tags: java, html, json, jsoup

Please note that I am no Java expert, I would however appreciate any help and guidance where possible.

I have a piece of Java code that reads the contents of a files and parses it to html using JSOUP. I then need to convert a table into JSON. The first row converts successfully, but none of the following rows are getting converted.

I am sure that something simple is missing that I am over looking, so would appreciate any guidance / assistance.

My program below:

```
package html_to_json_parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class HTML_to_JSON_parser {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("skills_table.html"); 
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
    String line = buf.readLine(); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    while(line != null){
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
        line = buf.readLine(); 
    }

    String htmlFile = sb.toString(); 

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject();
    Element table = doc.select("table").first();
    Elements row = table.getElementsByTag("tr");        

        for (int j = 0, k = row.size(); j < k; j++) {

            Elements cols = row.select("td");
            String skill = cols.get(0).text();
            String beginner = cols.get(1).text();
            String intermediate = cols.get(2).text();
            String advanced = cols.get(3).text();
            jsonObject.put("Beginner", beginner);
            jsonObject.put("Intermediate", intermediate);
            jsonObject.put("Advanced", advanced);
            jsonParentObject.put(skill,jsonObject);
         }

    System.out.println(jsonParentObject.toString());

    }

}
```

HTML table that needs to be converted to JSON:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skill</th>
      <th>Beginner</th>
      <th>Intermediate</th>
      <th>Advanced</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Reading</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Speaking</td>
      <td>◯</td>
      <td>✔</td>
      <td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Writing</td>
      <td>◯</td>
      <td>◯</td>
      <td>✔</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Interacting</td>
      <td>●</td>
      <td>●</td>
      <td>● ●</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Require JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "skill": "reading",
        "beginner": "✔",
        "intermediate": "✔",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "writing",
        "beginner": "◯",
        "intermediate": "✔",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "speaking",
        "beginner": "◯",
        "intermediate": "◯",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "interacting",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    }
]
```

Your guidance and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this returns `row.size()`

Comment: Hi @SagarRohankar, It returns 5, for the five rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element table = doc.select("tbody").first();
```

Replace "tbody" instead of "table"

And

```
Elements cols = row.eq (j).select("td");
```

Change like above, here you missed to get jth tr element and extract details.

Btw you can also use get () instead of eq () that will also work

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

Ew.. Big mistake. You shoud put above initiation inside for loop. Because for every for loop it is just updating same object's parameters thus it results in lastly updated details.

Comment: Hi @Vinujan. S, thanks, tried that. Still only converts the first row: "Reading".

Comment: Thanks, it is now looping through each row, but applying only columns ("td") from last row to every other row.

Comment: I didnt get it. can you please put sample output

Comment: Output looks like:
[
    {
        "skill": "reading",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    },
    {
        "skill": "writing",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    },
    {
        "skill": "speaking",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    },
    {
        "skill": "interacting",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    }
]

Comment: Should look like:
[
    {
        "skill": "reading",
        "beginner": "✔",
        "intermediate": "✔",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "writing",
        "beginner": "◯",
        "intermediate": "✔",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "speaking",
        "beginner": "◯",
        "intermediate": "◯",
        "advanced": "✔"
    },
    {
        "skill": "interacting",
        "beginner": "●",
        "intermediate": "●",
        "advanced": "● ●"
    }
]

Comment: Explanation added. Happy solving this problem with you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same row over and over again here:

```
Elements row = table.getElementsByTag("tr");        

for (int j = 0, k = row.size(); j < k; j++) {
    Elements cols = row.select("td");
```

You need to get the right row on every loop:

```
Elements cols = row.get(j).select("td");
```